# Pyimagej conda install for use with JupyterLab Notebook, how do I resolve maven dependancy?

Tags: maven, conda, pyimagej

The installation using conda was straight forward with no errors. There was an extra step not mentioned in the installation guide to add the newly created  pyimagej environment binary path to $PATH so Jupyterlab could find it. But then in testing the installation like so

```
python -c 'import imagej; ij = imagej.init("2.1.0"); print(ij.getVersion()); ij.dispose()'
```

an error occurred

```
Error in `/home/jovyan/my-conda-envs/pyimagej/bin/mvn -B -f /home/jovyan/.jgo/net.imglib2/imglib2-imglyb/1.0.0/9e796eff1b90c97afb3f66a15468d81ac27279585d244c8fee005bdda9380f06/pom.xml dependency:resolve': 1
```

After some searching it seems that something called maven can't find one of its dependencies.

The contents of the pom.xml file which is mentioned in the error message.

```
<project>
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>net.imglib2-BOOTSTRAPPER</groupId>
        <artifactId>imglib2-imglyb-BOOTSTRAPPER</artifactId>
        <version>0</version>
        <dependencyManagement>
                <dependencies><dependency><groupId>net.imglib2</groupId><artifactId>imglib2-imglyb</artifactId><version>1.0.0</version><type>pom</type><scope>import</scope></dependency></dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies><dependency><groupId>net.imglib2</groupId><artifactId>imglib2-imglyb</artifactId><version>1.0.0</version></dependency><dependency><groupId>net.imagej</groupId><artifactId>imagej</artifactId><version>2.1.0</version></dependency></dependencies>
        <repositories><repository><id>1</id><url>https://maven.scijava.org/content/repositories/releases</url></repository></repositories>
</project>
```

Can someone please tell me how to figure out what might be missing or not found.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: macOS Big Sur version 11.6